# Beautifulsoup get('value')

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<ul class="mainview">
    <li>
        <input value="ABCD" class="origianl">
    </li>
</ul>
```

this is HTML lines and

```
mainview = soup.find(class_="mainview")
child = mainview.children
child_value = child.get("value")
[print(x) for x in child_value]
```

this is the code i use in order to get "ABCD"

and always I get error says

```
AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I searched google and stackoverflow query but any of anwsers work for me...
How can I get value from input element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`children` (similar to `'list_iterator'`) means many items so you get list not single item. It can be even list with one item or empty list but it is still a list. You have to use `for` loop to use `get()` with every item on the list or use index `[0]` to get only first item (if list is not empty)

But in `BeautifulSoup` it gives all elements inside, not only `tags` (class `Tag`) but also `text` between tags (class `NavigableString`) which don't have `.get()` method.

This code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ul class="mainview">
    <li>
        <input value="ABCD" class="origianl">
    </li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

mainview = soup.find(class_="mainview")

for child in mainview.children:
    print(type(child))
```

gives

```
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
```

Better use next `find()` to find single element or `find_all()` to get list of elements.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<ul class="mainview">
    <li>
        <input value="ABCD" class="origianl">
    </li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

mainview = soup.find(class_="mainview")

child = mainview.find(class_="origianl")

print(child.get('value'))
```

---

**EDIT:**

`children` gives only first level of subitems (`<li>`), but not children in those subitems (`<input>`) so you would have to use inner `for` loop to get `<input>` which is in `<li>`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4

html = '''
<ul class="mainview">
    <li>
        <input value="ABCD" class="origianl">
    </li>
</ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

mainview = soup.find(class_="mainview")

print('--- children ---')
for child in mainview.children:
    print('>    tag:', child.name)
    print('>   type:', type(child))
    #print('>content:', child)
    if isinstance(child, bs4.element.Tag):
        print('>  value:', child.get('value'))
        print('          --- subchildren ---')
        for subchild in child.children:
            print('          >    tag:', subchild.name)
            print('          >   type:', type(subchild))
            #print('          >content:', subchild)
            if isinstance(subchild, bs4.element.Tag):
                print('          >  value:', subchild.get('value'))
            print('          -----------')

    print('-----------')
```

Result:

```
--- children ---
>    tag: None
>   type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
-----------
>    tag: li
>   type: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>  value: None
          --- subchildren ---
          >    tag: None
          >   type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
          -----------
          >    tag: input
          >   type: <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
          >  value: ABCD
          -----------
          >    tag: None
          >   type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
          -----------
-----------
>    tag: None
>   type: <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
-----------
```

Comment: thank you Even though there is only one input in my example, my work had series of input and I stupidly mistake that child has single value.

Comment: there is other problem - which I described right now. There are elements `NavigableString` which keeps only text inside tags and they don't have `.get()` method. You would have to check `if is_instance(child, Tag): child.get()`

Comment: btw: there is also other problem `mainview.children` gives only children on first level - it wil give `<li>` but not `<input>`. To get `<input>` you would have to find `<li>` in `mainview.children` and then gets its children`.